# how to make textureview to not be affected by configuration changes?

Tags: android, android-camera2, textureview, onconfigurationchanged

I am trying to make a camera application with a TextureView, I want to make my application so it will continue recording and show preview while configuration changes (such as orientation changes) without stopping, I trying to do it with ViewModel, but then I realized that I cant put views such as TextureView in model view, also onSaveInstanceState() callback will not help me because I don't want to restart at all when configuration happens.